# How to post the values when date picker changes the values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onchange

I would like to keep the session and stored the variable in the values. When someone changed the dates of the date picker, session variable values should be modified according to the selected values. I was trying to use an ajax call to set variables.

I'm tried with this thread: [Call a function when values of the date picker changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309742/call-a-function-when-values-of-the-date-picker-changes)

I didn't get the result the jquery script not working for me.

```
<div id="reportrange" class="selectbox "  style="border: 1px solid #ddd; border-radius: 4px; padding:5px; background: #fff; cursor: pointer; margin: 0  0 4px 0;overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
               <input type="hidden" id="selectdaterange" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['checkin'] ?> - <?php echo $_SESSION['checkout']?>" disabled/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
    alert("dhgfhgfhf");
    // var start = moment().add(1, 'days');
    // var end = moment().add(2, 'days');
    var start = moment('<?php echo $_SESSION['checkin'] ?>', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
    var end = moment('<?php echo $_SESSION['checkout '] ?>', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
    var min_date = moment().add(1, 'days');

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#selectdaterange').val(start.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        //  changeSession(); // alert (start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        "autoApply": true,
        "startDate": start,
        "endDate": end,
        "minDate": min_date,
        "opens": "right"
    }, cb);
    cb(start, end);
});

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#selectdaterange").change(function changeSession() {
    alert("gfgf");
    var start = document.getElementsByName('daterangepicker_start').value;
    var end = document.getElementsByName('daterangepicker_end').value;
    $.ajax({

        type: 'POST',
        data: 'checkin=' + start + '&checkout=' + end,
        url: 'function.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            alert("response.message");
        }
    });
}); 
});
```

Comment: Share the error what you get on the console for more detail.

Comment: use `.on('change')` in place of `.change()` function as `#selectdaterange` is dynamically generated.

Comment: changed .on('change') method but not working. Date range grayed out and $_SESSION['checkin'] and $_SESSION['checkout'] have some error like ERROR: undefined index checkin and checkout.